# How to get rid of noise in audio files?

Tags: fft, noise, python, spectrogram, r

Is there any method to get rid of noise in wite circles of the spectrogram? I have done the high pass filter for a cut-off frequency of 1 kHz. And I'v also done a adptive noise reduction in adbobe audition. But there are still some noise between bird-songs.
[image]

Can I get rid of them and get a cleaned spectrogram, which only have target object.
Any thoughts on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without much context about your audio signals, this looks like uniformly distributed low energy noise. Linear filtering may not work very well here, but a simple non-linear method can be suggested. Basically define a threshold of meaningful signal energy within a frequency band and then ignore frequency contributions below that threshold. Something like:

```
# Frequency analysis for non-linear filtering
X_w = np.fft.fft(x_t)
# Filter low energy noise components
max_freq_comp = np.max(np.abs(X_w))
X_w_ignore_low = np.where(np.abs(X_w) > max_freq_comp/10, X_w, 0+0j)
# Filter DC component
X_w_ignore_low[0] = 0+0j
```

You can check the full python program listing, I responded to a similar question [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75389/can-simple-fir-iir-filtering-recover-estimate-a-signal-plagued-with-low-snr-whit#comment160626_75389)